# Prove you can weigh any number between 1 and $\frac{3^{n+1} -1}{2}$ using $n+1$ weights - Discrete

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ternary-expansion

You have $n+1$ weights, with each weighing $1,3,9, \dots, 3^n$  (one of each)

Prove that you can weigh with a traditional scale ( The one with two bowls) each integer weight between  $$1 ~~~~~\text{And }~~~~~\frac{3^{n+1} -1}{2}$$

My go:
This was very confusing to me because I did not understand well how you can possibly weigh, let's say $4$ (Maybe it's just putting $1+3$ ?)

I tried proving using induction:

1. If $n=0$ then we have $1$ weight weighing 1, and so we can weigh $\frac{3^1 -1}{2} ~~~ \text{And} ~~~ 1 = 1$  which is obvious.
2. Assume you have $n+1$ weights and you can weigh each integer between $1$ and $\frac{3^{k+1} -1}{2}$
3. Now we prove for $n = k+1$ so: $1$ to $\frac{3^{k+2}-1}{2}$ using the fact we can weigh $\frac{3^{k+1} -1}{2}$
   However I am stuck from here, I am clueless on how to use the fact we now have a weight of $1,3,9,\dots,3^k,3^{k+1}$

This seems like a known question, but I could not find anything on the web!
Thank you!

Comment: Is there only one weight of each kind? If there are **2 weights of each kind**, then it is possible. Because it will become a base 3 number system and hence any number can be written in that form.

Comment: @JohnBrookfields Yeah that's exactly what I thought! like base 6 or 5 ... but nope you have only 1 of each

Comment: Yes, @PeterForeman, I thought the same too. I was just editing that comment for that and working on the math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prove each such integer is of the form $\sum_{j=0}^na_j3^j$ with $a_j\in\{-1,\,0,\,1\}$. Equivalently, adding $\sum_j3^j=\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}$ to the integer, we wish to prove every integer from $\frac{3^{n+1}+1}{2}$ to $3^{n+1}-1$ is of the form $\sum_{j=0}^na_j3^j$ with $a_j\in\{0,\,1,\,2\}$. But that's trivial; just write it in base $3$.

For an inductive variant, note the case $n=0$ is trivial, and to go from $n=k$ to $n=k+1$ write each integer from $0$ to $\frac{3^{k+2}-1}{2}$ as $3m+j$ with $-1\le j\le1,\,0\le m\le\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2}$. By the inductive hypothesis, $m$ is of the form $\sum_{j=0}^ka_j3^j$, so $3m+j$ is of the same form but with the upper limit changed to $k+1$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Is it possible to prove using induction? or the way you specified is easier? Thanks!

Comment: @PeterForeman Sorry I still dont understand... I have only 1 weight of each size, so base 3 cannot exist with 1 weight

Comment: @Remember1312 Two things. Firstly, sorry for responding to a comment you wrote on the other answer; that was a mistake. I've added an inductive argument to my answer. Secondly, the original coefficients from $-1$ to $1$ indicate whether you place a weight on one side, neither or the other, whereas coefficients from $0$ to $2$ are one more than such a $-1$-to-$1$ coefficient, *not* an overall number of copies needed. So even a $2$ doesn't mean you need two identical weights.

Comment: @Remember1312 An $n=2$ example: to weigh $11$ add $(3^3-1)/2=13$, then note $24$ becomes $220$ in base $3$, so $a_0=-1,\,a_1=a_2=1$. Therefore, balance the $11$ and $1$ against $3$ and $9$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem.

One solution: write $n$ in base $3$ using the digits $0, \pm 1$ instead of the digits $0,1,2$. That's [balanced ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary). Then use the coefficients to determine which weights go on which side of the balance. For example,
$$
16 = 27 - 9 - 3 + 1
$$
tells you that a weight of $16$ together with a  $9$ and a $3$ will balance a $27$ and a $1$.

See
[https://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/weighing.pdf](https://www.cs.umb.edu/%7Eeb/weighing.pdf) for a paper on this topic in recreational mathematics, to appear in Mathematics Magazine.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Is it possible to prove using induction? or the way you specified is easier? Thanks!

Comment: @Remember1312 I use the fact that integers from $0$ to $3^{n+1}-1$ have at most $n+1$ digits in base $3$. You could prove that by induction.

Comment: @J.G. I am still stuck on the proof, can you please give me a clue on where to start? I would prefer if it was using induction (complete or regular)